# Unity - stop animation loop

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

How can I stop make unity continuous looping

what I have done

1- I add animator to my object.

2- I create animator controller

3- I create my animation

4- finally link my animation controller to my object

[image]

it works just fine , but it keep looping

how can I make it animate just once

Comment: do you mean the main loop that refreshes the screen?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In your project panel select your animation and in inspector **unCheck Loop Time** property. That will stop looping your animation :)

Comment: I unchecked loop time both in and out of play mode and it's still looping

Comment: For anyone else wondering why it doesn't work. Click **Apply** ...